# How can I render an HTML view while constructing a JSON response in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, partial-views

I have a controller method that returns JSON. But sometimes part of that JSON object should include a rendered, serialized HTML view. So my controller method has a line like this:

```
html = render_to_string :partial => 'foo/bar'
# ...
render json: {x: 'y', html: html}
```

But that fails because Rails is only looking for JSON views!

> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing partial foo/bar with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :slim, :haml]}. […]

How can I solve this?

---

**Update**: I have gotten one "level" of layout to `render_to_string` as html using the below syntax, but the same error persists when that layout renders its own partials!

```
html = render_to_string :partial => "foo/bar.html.haml"
```

Surely there’s a solution here, right?

---

**Update 2**: `render_to_string :action => 'method_in_this_controller'` seems to be doing the trick.

Comment: try: `html = render_to_string :partial => 'foo/bar', :formats=>[:html]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I may be doing it wrong, but that doesn't seem to  do the trick.

Comment: Would it be good to make 2 request? one for the html if needed, and after that the json?  Single purpose is always good.  May take a few more lines of code and an extra ajax call.  But who knows.  Just my 2cents.

Comment: A good suggestion, Phu Phan; but since this will be used in a mobile app, it makes sense to avoid needless extra HTTP requests. I don’t understand why this is so difficult; surely it’s a common-enough use case, right?

Answer (score 2):

Repeating Yanhao's answer because I ran into this exact problem and its what worked for me.

try:

```
html = render_to_string :partial => 'foo/bar', :formats=>[:html]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am writing something like that in my action:

```
def show
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :json => data }
  end
end
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: Where are you rendering a template to HTML within your method?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a file 'apps/views/foo/_bar.*'? I was able to render HTML as a JSON parameter with [How do I render a partial to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726007/how-do-i-render-a-partial-to-a-string)

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to post_path(post) }
   format.js { 
     render json: { 
       error: flash[:error],
       content: (render_to_string partial: '/comments/comment', locals: {comment: comment}, layout: false )  
     } 
   }
end
```