# Add support for rendering views to a rails api only application

Tags: ruby, azure, templates, ruby-on-rails-5, postmark

I built an api only rails app, but since i'm using a 3rd party email service, I need to be able to render the email template into a string to pass it to the mailing service wrapper gem. So far any attempt to render templates into a string returns an empty string, and i suspect it is because the application is configured to be API only. Ho do I add support to rendering templates into a string?

If this is not the case, please let me know. I'm using postmark mail service. `postmark-rails` gem, which integrates into standard rails mailers didn't work at all, and plain `postmark` gem (which uses postmark API instead of postmark SMTP server) works fine, but now my problem is producing the proper html for the email.

this is what I'm trying:

```
html = render_to_string(
            partial: "transfer_mailer/transfer.html.erb",
            locals: {
                :@body => @body,
                :@campaign => @campaign,
                :@chat => @chat
                }
        )
```

but it returns empty string.

My setup involves `Rails 5.0.1`, `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]`, `Sidekiq 4.2.7`, and in production im using `nginx/1.10.2` and `Phusion Passenger 5.1.1`. Production environment is deployed in an azure virtual machine, and I added both inbound and outbound rules for allowing traffic through ports 25, 465, 2525, and 587.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs for `render_to_string`, it looks like the path doesn't need to include `.html.erb`, so maybe removing that will fix it.

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20726120/2981429) for some example code:

In your case, it would be:

```
   render_to_string(
       partial: '/transfer_mailer/transfer',
        locals: {
            :@body => @body,
            :@campaign => @campaign,
            :@chat => @chat
        },
       layout: false
    )
```

Also make sure the partial filename  starts with an underscore, even though you don't include it with `render_to_string` or `render` calls.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not the case, especially because I have two templates: one that finishes in `html.erb` and the other in `text.erb`. This is normal when it comes to mailer templates. For now, my workaround is including `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper` in the controller, loading the file in a `File` instance, reading it and passing it to `ERB` as explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14351129/667599). Anyways, thanks for your help :).

Answer (score 0):

There is the other way to use `render_to_string` for resolving your issue. Please see the code below.

```
@body = XXX
@campaign = YYY
@chat = ZZZ
html = render_to_string(
  file: 'transfer_mailer/transfer.html.erb'
)
```

Hope it helps.