# Changing Rails Pages to UI.router pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

Half of the current project that I am working on is written in angularjs while most critical parts are written in Rails.

Is it possible to use angular without rewriting all the rails pages ?

At the end of the day, Rails is already handling all business logic in backend. All I want is a neat way of using angular to render that data without reloading page to fetch the templates rendered by Rails.

So it is possible to get partial of a page by changing my application.html.erb to just one line of code:

```
<%= yield %>
```

Now, If I reload the url rails only returns the part of page relevant to the specific business logic from controller that should handle the request.

No I need to do is 
- Use angular to render the footer and header for these pages
- Handle a page reload logic, so that on a full page reload, it should load the single page app and then render the current view.

Comment: you could retreive partial from rails and wrap it under a route in ui.router

Comment: Will that mean rewriting all Rails pages to return without header and footer ?

Comment: You might not need to do that, check for your appliction.erb.html there you can define a logic  to conditionally return header and footer.

Comment: You could also have your rails api return a string respresentation of a certain partial with `render_to_string partial: '...', locals: { some_date: [] }` and then use that in your angularjs app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726007/how-do-i-render-a-partial-to-a-string

Comment: and then I can make angular compile string into view, makes sense

Comment: Read the post here : https://medium.com/@nshnt/migrating-rails-pages-to-angularjs-6c01ced6cb88

Comment: this has been put on hold ? @Rob not sure why would you assume it lacks research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the blog : https://medium.com/@nshnt/migrating-rails-pages-to-angularjs-6c01ced6cb88, here is what seems to work

If request has a partial=true query param, server returns the partial, without header and footer.

```
helper_method  :should_render_partial?, .... 

def should_render_partial?
    params[:partial].eql?("true")
end
```

In the template :

```
<% unless should_render_partial? %>
    <%= render partial: 'layouts/angular_app_template' %>
<% end %>

<% if should_render_partial? %>
    <%= yield %>
<% end %>
```

In angular, using ui.router the same partial can be rendered :

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: function(){
    return "/home?partial=true";
  },
});
```